# Syntax for cakePHP findAll

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, findall

```
$lg = $this->Log->findAll('Log.log_user_id='.$user[0]['User']['id'], 'Log.created' DESC');
    $this->set('lg', $lg);
```

Returns SQL error
Need to sort the findAll by created DESC (most recent on top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do what you are asking:

```
$lg = 
    $this->Log->find('all',
                     array('conditions' => array( 
                               'Log.log_user_id' => $user[0]['User']['id']
                                                ),
                           'order' => array('Log.created DESC')
                           )
                     );
```

Or you should be able to do it like this:

```
$lg =
    $this->Log->findAllByLogUserId($user[0]['User']['id'], 
                                   array(),  
                                   array('Log.created' => 'desc'));
```

What SQL Error message are you getting?  It should have printed it out.

Comment: I used a combination of my initial code and the 2nd suggestion. Thanks.
    $lg = $this->Log->findAll('Log.log_user_id='.$user[0]['User']['id'], // then your suggestion
    array(),  
                                   array('Log.created' => 'desc')); // then
    $this->set('lg', $lg);